# IPHONE - Use multiple views

Tags: iphone

I have to make an application with six views, which can be accessed to by bar button items on a toolbar.

I'm really new at this.
I have a view controller and a XIB file for each view, with six functions (goToView1, goToView2, ..., goToView6).

Here is an example :

```
SecondViewController *secondview;

-(IBAction)goToView2 {
    secondview = [[SecondViewController alloc] 
                 initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:secondview.view];
}
```

But as you can see, if I want to go from view3 to view2, I'm not deleting the view3 from the stack : I'm just adding the view2 over it.
So here's my problem, how do I "delete" my view before using addSubView ?
I tried with removeFromSuperView, but I think I'm not using it right.

Thanks for helping, as I said I'm really new and I am aware it can be a stupid question :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds very much like you want to use a [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as this will provide the toolbar (with icons), etc. and will automatically handle displaying the appropriate view controller when a specific toolbar icon is selected.

However, I'd really recommend first reading the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) document, as it provides a good overview of the various UIKit controllers, etc. and how they should be used. If you take the time to read and understand this now, it'll serve you well in the future.

Comment: Hi, if I use a UITabBarController, will my app still work ? (because I have some elements working already even if I can't manage the navigation yet)

Comment: @nax_ You should be able to use your existing view controllers as-is - the UITabBarController will simply provide the toolbar/view controller selection mechanism.

Comment: I also recommend starting with a tab bar controller. The UIViewController class reference warns you against adding a view controller's view as a subview. Like you are doing now. You are likely to be confused as to why methods on you nested view controllers are not being called if you continue with this design.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at UITabBar. I think using a tab bar might be better suited for what you want to do, than a toolbar.

[UITabBar Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

to remove the fisrt view you should use something like this.

```
   [fisrtView removefromSuperview];
```

put in where you want to remove view.